# How to create a new_X_path url dinamically in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link in my partial template:

```
link_to 'Add', new_photo_path
```

But I want to make this partial template shared. Is there any way to make 'new_CONTROLLER_path' url automatically? The CONTROLLER must be replaced by current controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
link_to 'Add', [:new, params[:controller].singularize]
```

Internally, `Rails` will convert `[:new, params[:controller].singularize]` to a call to `new_controller_name_path`(e.g. if controller `posts` then `[:new, params[:controller].singularize]` generate a path helper like `new_post_path`).

<sub>Most (if not all) `Rails` methods that expect a path will also take an object representation of your resource, like `respond_with`, `link_to`, `render`, `redirect_to`, `form_for`, etc.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
link_to 'Add', eval("new_#{params[:contoller].singularize}_path")
```

`params[:contoller].singularize` will return you `photo` or any controller name related to request eval will do rest.

Comment: i can pass to the `params[:controller]` a malicious code. It's very dangerous

Comment: It will take you to 404 error, before serving the desired page. As I know.

Comment: Nickey, what about
`params[:controller]  = " ||= ''; raise('ololo, bitch');root"`
`eval("new_#{params[:controller].singularize}_path")`

?
:)

Comment: Is this code " ||=" will entertain by rails controller. Answer is no. Before Proceeding to view it will raise 404 error.

Comment: check this `eval("foo_#{%x|ls -la|.upcase}bar_path")` it will run code before server can render 404.

Comment: Зелёный, actually we can't override `params[:controller]` or params[:action] - rails replaces values of these keys. So Nickey is right here about the fact it is "safe". But still isn't right by doing eval.

Comment: @intale ok, it's make sense.

Comment: The correct solution should should be:  
`link_to("New", {:controller => controller_name, :action => :new})`